# Validate form input for domains and IPs - ajax

Tags: ajax, regex, validation, forms

how to validate a form field that gets submitted through ajax (below). It needs to validate against a domain (.com, .net, .se etc.) and an IP address. Basically it has to look for at least one dot and at least two letters after last dot.

Now I only have an empty field validation:

```
var domain = $("input#domain").val();  
        if (domain == "") {  
       $("label#domain_error").show();  
       $("input#domain").focus();  
       return false;  
     }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use regular expressions:

For the IP address:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

For the hostname:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

For an example how to use regular expressions in JavaScript, have a look at [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Comment: So I assume I'd write two if loops: 1) if (domain == ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$) - error IP and 2) else if (domain == ^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$) - error domain ??

Comment: Have a look at how to use regex in JavaScript: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: I tried this. It's terrible logic, but should work, unfortunately it doesn't: `code`var rege = /^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/;
    var domain = $("input#domain").val(); 
    if (rege.test(domain)){ 
       // do nothing
    }
    else
        //if (domain == "") {  
       $("label#domain_error").show();  
       $("input#domain").focus();  
       return false;  `code`